# Alter the text displayed for a token in ace-editor

Tags: ace-editor

I have this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/thetallweeks/6qg7at91/29/) where I am locating a matching string via regex and changing the styles using highlight rules.

```
this.$rules = {
  start: [{
    token: 'variableRef',
    regex: /\$variable\..+\$/
  }]
};
```

and alter the color using a css class:

```
.ace_variableRef {
  color: red;
}
```

But what I would really like to do is change the text that is being displayed from $variable.1.name$ to the "resolved value". I have access to:

```
var variables = {
  1: 'timeout'
};
```

so I can use the reference path to get the value, but is it even possible to do this with ace-editor?

Ideally I would display the string in the user friendly way, but keep the original reference value handy (in metadata or something) since that is what is actually stored in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by defining a custom onMatch for your rule, like so

```js
    this.$rules = {
      start: [{
        onMatch: function(value, state, stack) {
          var values = this.splitRegex.exec(value);
          return [{
            type: 'variableRef',
            value: variables[values[1]]
          }]
        },
        regex: /\$variable\.(\d+).+\$/
      }]
    };
```

but the actual text will remain unaltered (thus causing oddities with text selection/cursor), so you'll need to pad/clip the resulting `value` for it to match length of values[0]

Comment: It's good to know the value needs to be padded/clipped to keep the length the same. That is going to be annoying :)

Comment: Hi, I need to do almost the same as you and I face the pad/clip problem. In fact, I want to add metadatas in text and remove it from display. Did you find any solutions ?

Comment: I do not believe that anything has changed in this regard since then - a lot of things in Ace work on assumption that N-th symbol on the line will always be (N-1)*(reference character width) away from left edge, and this is not an easy thing to change ([GH issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/460)).